# Google Sheets API - How do do a batchUpdateRequest with append requests?

Tags: python, google-sheets-api

I'm running into a bit of a wall here.

I'm pulling in some data that I pull in via an API, which I transform and then append it to the bottom of a sheet in Google Sheets. For each line of data that I pull, I currently use an append() request.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of calls I make, and batchUpdate seems like a good start. However, out of the available options for batchUpdate, append doesn't seem to be present, or I'm misreading it.

My end goal is that I can get a bunch of data and append them to the bottom of a spreadsheet, instead of continuously calling the append endpoint.

Comment: Have you had a look at [`gspread`](https://github.com/burnash/gspread)? It makes the API a lot more simple to work with, in a similar way as `requests` does to `urllib`. You can read/update blocks of cells in a single call.

Comment: I have, but this is gonna be in a production environment and utilizing 3rd party modules is pretty difficult :[ I think I can do a batchupdate for updating several cells at once, but the append functionality means I don't need to specify ranges or anything. Instead, I just want to queue up a bunch of append actions so it counts as a single API call.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're just looking at the [Values](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values) collection.  It doesn't make much sense to do a batchAppend because all you'd be doing is appending to the end of the prior one.. so you might as well just make a single append call with all the data you'd like to append.

However, if you'd like to intermix updating various other aspects of the spreadsheet (not just the values), then you can use [spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate).  One of the kinds of requests that can do is an [AppendCellsRequest](https://devsite.googleplex.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#appendcellsrequest).

However, it's not clear why you need to batch in the first place.  With batchUpdate it makes sense because each update is going to an exact place in the sheet so you can bundle a lot of updates together.  OTOH, "append" doesn't specify the location, it just says "go after the existing data", so there's no point to batching them up, you can just as easily make a single call w/ all the data you'd like to append.